# Maian Tool Repository on Docker: How to store contract retrieved from etherscan.io and what is ‘test.sol’

Tags: testing, docker

I am in the MAIAN tool repository on docker. The link at :
[MAIAN Tool GitHub Link](https://github.com/ivicanikolicsg/MAIAN/issues/26)

They provided details of how to execute the MAIAN tool from docker. I am in the MAIAN tool repository on docker.
They have first tried to access the contract from docker:

[Accessing contract KaratBankCoin using Etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/address/0xf3586684107ce0859c44aa2b2e0fb8cd8731a15a#code)

The name of the contract is KaratBankCoin. They have not told where to store the contract.

Later on they used the command:

> `python maian.py -c 2 --soliditycode test.sol KaratBankCoin`

I am getting the error :

> ==================================================================================================== [ ] Compiling Solidity contract from the file test.sol ... [-]
> Contract file test.sol does NOT exist [-] Contract KaratBankCoin does
> NOT exist

Because I don’t know what is test.sol and I don’t know  how and where to store the KaratBankCoin contract retrieved from mainnet.

They have not provided any details about test.sol and how to store KaratBanCoin because we are in the Maian tool’s repository.

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.